# What are unit/helpers for - classes inherited from ActionView::TestCase?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, helper

I cant find any mention of these classes typically called HelperTest in Rails Guides or Agile Web Development with Rails.
Searching the Net seems to reveal that most people use them to test helpers.
But why then does scaffold create one of these per model class?
And why is it placed under test\units?
I would be grateful of a good example for where and how these should be used.
Is it wrong just to remove such helper files generated by scaffold if they are not used?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out, the scaffold generator (here, for 'posts') creates the helper tests under `test/unit/helpers`:

```
test
├── fixtures
│   └── posts.yml
├── functional
│   └── posts_controller_test.rb
├── integration
├── performance
│   └── browsing_test.rb
├── test_helper.rb
└── unit
    ├── helpers
    │   └── posts_helper_test.rb
    └── post_test.rb
```

They're unit tests because helpers are just methods that should be tested alone; also, if you believe that views should be kept lightweight, that can mean that helpers end up with a lot of logic and should be tested just like your models.

So, given this helper (in app/helpers/posts_helper.rb)

```
module PostsHelper

  def hello
    content_tag :div, :class => "detail" do
      "hi"
    end
  end
end
```

you can write a test like so:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostsHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  test "hello" do
    assert_equal(hello, "<div class=\"detail\">hi</div>")
  end

end
```

They're just methods, so use the same matchers as you would in any unit test (`assert_equal`, `assert_match`); `assert_dom_equal` comes in handy here too. (see http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/assert_dom_equal/

I hope this helps :)

Kyle

Comment: Thanks Kyle, that does really help.
I had wrongly assumed that these were helpers for the model unit tests but couldn't quite see why you would want those either.
I presume that the helper tests are run along with all other unit tests in rake test:units ?